# Why onitemcommand of repeater control not working in this case?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, repeater

I have Image in ItemTemplate that will be changing according to Username (ie lblPostedBy.Text). I have written code in onItemCommand of repeater control in C# Asp.net 4.0. But not working. Will you please help me.

```
protected void myrepeater_ItemCommand1(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    // Actually lblPostedBy is a linkbutton and lblPostedBy.Text is 'username of the commenter'.
    LinkButton lblPostedBy = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lblPostedBy");
    con.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "select image from " + lblPostedBy.Text + " where id=1";
    // 'image' column in table stores path of image like '~/image/image1.jpg'
    cmd.Connection = con;
    string imageurl = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    con.Close();
    Image Image1 = (Image)e.Item.FindControl("Image1");
    Image1.ImageUrl = imageurl;
}
```

and

```
<asp:Repeater ID="myrepeater" runat="server" 
    onitemcommand="myrepeater_ItemCommand1">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table width="100%" style="font: 8pt verdana">
                <tr style="background-color:#3C78C3">
                    <th>NEWS FEED</th>
                </tr>

        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top">
                   <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="50px" />
                   <asp:LinkButton ID="lblPostedBy" runat="server" onclick="lblPostedBy_Click" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.postedby") %>' /> &nbsp says : <br />
                   <asp:TextBox id="txtPost" runat="server"  Width="100%" textmode="multiline" text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.scraps")%>' ReadOnly="True" BackColor="#EFF3FB" BorderStyle="None"></asp:TextBox> 
                   <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.scraptime") %>
                   <br />
                   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Visible="False" Width="80%"></asp:TextBox>
                   <asp:Button ID="btnDoneComment" runat="server" Text="Done" Visible="False" onclick="btnDoneComment_Click"/>
                   <br />
                   <hr style="border:dashed 1px blue" />
                </td>
           </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Thanks in Advance,

Regards,
Nikhil

Comment: Thank you Mr. abatishchev for editing.

Comment: I figured this that onItemCommand is is not fired at Page_Load but fires when a button is clicked inside Repeater Control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of "cmd.CommandText = "select image from " + lblPostedBy.Text;"

Shouldn't it be

```
cmd.CommandText = "select image from TableName where pby = '" + lblPostedBy.Text + "'";
```

Better yet, add a parameter

```
cmd.CommandText = "select image from tablename where pby = @pby"
```

`cmd.Parameters.Add(new SalParameter("@pby", lblPostedBy.Text);`

Comment: What's the error message?  Did you use "select image from TableName where pby = '" + lblPostedBy.Text + "'" or the parameter version?

Comment: I used : cmd.CommandText = "select image from " + lblPostedBy.Text + " where id=1"; //that will be retrieving image column from table that hold path of image like '~/image/image1.jpg'

Comment: So you have a table for every poster?  The syntax is "SELECT ColumnName FROM TableName WHERE Condition1 AND Condition2

Comment: Please post the table definition with the table name and the names of the columns

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3246/discussion-between-karel-and-nikhil-tamhankar)

Comment: Sorry, I was unable to chat yesterday. Karel, I have placed the button inside my repeater control and when I click it, image comes. That means onitemcommand is not working, right?

Comment: want to load profile image of user in Image1. I will give Image1.imageurl="DB's column of imageurl".